# rpmbuild - issues with ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}

Tags: rpmbuild

The powers that be have decided that I have to use this tool which I've grown to hate in a short time.

I have packed a few things (binary, script, library) on a tarball that I want to put in a secluded place... specifically under $HOME but it could be anywhere.  I can get all that to work but everything under %files automatically prepends my rpm's buildroot, which happens to be ~/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/blah/blah.

I'm actually using a template from a colleague, but getting nowhere.  Tried changing ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT} but that has the same results: installing everything to the root directory.  Here's what I assume are the interesting parts.  Again, it's just a program I made, something to kick it off, and a library it requires.

```
Source0: %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz

%install
rm -rf ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}
mkdir -p ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/MyApp
/bin/tar -C ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT} -xf ${RPM_SOURCE_DIR}/${RPM_PACKAGE_NAME}-${RPM_PACKAGE_VERSION}.tar.gz

%files
%defattr(7550,root,root,-)
/MyApp.1.0-r10
/MyApp.py
/lib/libMyLibrary.so.1.0.0
```

If I change the tar line in %install to chdir to ${HOME} it copies the files there, but then %files fails, due to the prepending issue.

Comment: `%prep` and `%setup` will take care of untarring your binaries, in %install you need to copy them in place (which will be relative to the build root)

Comment: Check out this doco I wrote which you might find helpful:
https://github.com/haani-niyaz/sysadmincrumbs/blob/master/rpmbuild/RPMBUILD.md